# In the "least-squares" minimization problem, is the solution unique?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, least-squares

I want to minimize:

$$\min f(a,b)= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(ax_i+b-y_i)^2 $$

I an do this by setting the gradient equal to zero which leaves me with two equations and two unknowns.

**Gradient:** $$\nabla f=\begin{pmatrix} \partial_a f \\ \partial_bf  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i(ax_i+b-y_i) \\ \sum_{i=1}^n ax_i+b-y_i\end{pmatrix}$$

After a bit of algebra I get:

$$a=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \\ b= \frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i-a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)$$

> Is this solution unique? Is there any way to see this right way or do
>   I have to convert this to matrix form and look at the column space of
>   $A$?

Comment: If you 2 equations in 2 unknowns, then you either have a unique solution or no solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the solution is unique depends on the input data. If $x_i$ is the same for all $i$, you can set $a$ arbitrarily, and let $b=y_i - \sum_i a x_i$.

By looking at the Hessian and relating it to convexity and strict convexity, you will see that the solution is unique whenever $x_i$ is not the same for all $i$.

Comment: Oh my I think I made a terrible mistake. $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 $$

if and only if all $x_i$ are equal. So the determinant of the hessian is only $0$ if all $x_i $ are the same (which is what you were saying in your answer but I only just got that). If they are not the same the hessian is positive definite and $(a,b)$ is a global minimum .

Comment: @qnd you are missing a factor $\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n$ in your last comment